# Threading vs Task-Based vs Asynchronous Programming

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm new to this concept. Are these the same or different things? What is the difference? I really like the idea of being able to run two processes at once, for example if I have several large files to load into my program I'd love to load as many of them simultaneously as possible instead of waiting for one at a time. And when working with a large file, such as wav file, it would be great to break it into pieces and do processing on several chunks at once and then put them back together. What do I want to look into to learn how to do this sort of thing?

Edit: Also, I know using more than one core on a multicore processor fits in here somewhere, but apparently asynchronous programming doesn't necessarily mean you are using multiple cores? Why would you do this if you didn't have multiple cores to take advantage of?

Comment: Asynchronous doesn't necessarily mean multiple threads. Loading multiple files concurrently might not save you any time and in fact could be slower because the disk drive can only do one thing at a time. You'll want to increase your file's input buffer to 64K or so. In general, the way you learn about this stuff is to get a tutorial and start using it. I don't have any recommendations for C++, though.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question completely since there would be a lot to say, but a good way to understand asynchronous programming is to write a program using several threads and function callbacks.

Comment: If I have multiple cores, it seems like processing a large file in separate chunks on different cores would certainly increase performance though. Would I be able to do that with std::thread? If threading isn't the only way to run something asynchronously, what are the other ways?

Comment: Scott Meyers in his latest Effective Modern C++ has a section on C++11 concurrency and the difference between thread and task usage [Item 35: Prefer task based programming to thread based](https://books.google.com/books?id=rjhIBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA241&ots=Fl1O31qBsZ&dq=Prefer%20task-based%20programming%20to%20thread-programming&pg=PA241#v=onepage&q=Prefer%20task-based%20programming%20to%20thread-programming&f=false)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

They are related but different.

*Threading,* normally called *multi-threading,* refers to the use of multiple threads of execution within a single process.  This usually refers to the simple case of using a small set of threads each doing different tasks that need to be, or could benefit from, running simultaneously. For example, a GUI application might have one thread draw elements, another thread respond to events like mouse clicks, and another thread do some background processing.

However, when the number of threads, each doing their own thing, is taken to an extreme, we usually start to talk about an [Agent-based approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent-based_model).

The *task-based* approach refers to a specific strategy in software engineering where, in abstract terms, you dynamically create "tasks" to be accomplished, and these tasks are picked up by a task manager that assigns the tasks to threads that can accomplish them. This is more of a software architectural thing. The advantage here is that the execution of the whole program is a succession of tasks being relayed (task A finished -> trigger task B, when both task B and task C are done -> trigger task D, etc..), instead of having to write a big function or program that executes each task one after the other. This gives flexibility when it is unclear which tasks will take more time than others, and when tasks are only loosely coupled. This is usually implemented with a [thread-pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) (threads that are waiting to be assigned a task) and some [message-passing interface (MPI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) to communicate data and task "contracts".

*Asynchronous programming* does not refer to multi-threaded programming, although the two are very often associated (and work well together). A *synchronous* program must complete each step before moving on to the next. An *asynchronous* program starts a step, moves on to other steps that don't require the result of the first step, then checks on the result of the first step when its result is required.

That is, a synchronous program might go a little bit like this: "do this task", "wait until done", "do something with the result", and "move on to something else". By contrast, an asynchronous program might go a little more like this: "I'm gonna start a task, and I'll need the result later, but I don't need it just now", "in the meantime, I'll do something else", "I can't do anything else until I have the result of the first step now, so I'll wait for it, if it isn't ready", and "move on to something else".

Notice that "asynchronous" refers to a [very broad concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony), that always involves some form of "start some work and tell me when it's done" instead of the traditional "do it now!". This does not require multi-threading, in which case it just becomes a software design choice (which often involves callback functions and things like that to provide "notification" of the asynchronous result). With multiple threads, it becomes more powerful, as you can do various things in parallel while the asynchronous task is working. Taken to the extreme, it can become a more full-blown architecture like a task-based approach (which is one kind of asynchronous programming technique).

I think the thing that you want corresponds more to yet another concept: [Parallel Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing) (or parallel processing). This approach is more about splitting a large processing task into smaller parts and processing all parts in parallel, and then combining the results. You should look into libraries like [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/) or OpenCL/CUDA (for [GPGPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPGPU)).  That said, you can use multi-threading for parallel processing.

> but apparently asynchronous programming doesn't necessarily mean you are using multiple cores?

Asynchronous programming does not necessarily involve anything happening concurrently in multiple threads. It could mean that the OS is doing things on your behalf behind the scenes (and will notify you when that work is finished), like in *asynchronous I/O,* which happens without you creating any threads. It boils down to being a software design choice.

> Why would you do this if you didn't have multiple cores to take advantage of?

If you don't have multiple cores, multi-threading can still improve performance by reusing "waiting time" (e.g., don't "block" the processing waiting on file or network I/O, or waiting on the user to click a mouse button). That means the program can do useful work while waiting on those things. Beyond that, it can provide flexibility in the design and make things seem to run simultaneously, which often makes users happier. Still, you are correct that before multi-core `CPU`s, there wasn't as much of an incentive to do multi-threading, as the gains often do not justify the overhead.

Comment: Thank you for that most detailed answer! So is parallel computing really so complex to implement as to require a library? I'm imagining simply splitting a very large array of audio samples (or several large arrays) into 4 segments, and using four instances of the same function to process each segment on a different processor core, then concatenating the four parts back together again. In my head this would make processing audio 4 times as fast, which would be significant since some of my functions take several minutes to complete. Is it, like so many things, not that simple?

Comment: @RobbyAllsopp It is that simple. You are right, it does not necessarily require a library. But a library like OpenMP (actually, it's a compiler extension, supported by most compilers) just makes it easier. Just look at the example of a [parallel for-loop](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#LoopDirectiveFor). It also makes it easier to switch it on or off, or to change the number of threads just with a compiler option.

Answer (score 1):

I think in general, all these are design related rather than language related. Same apply to multicore programming.

To reflect Jim, it's not only the file load scenario. Generally, you need to design the whole software to run concurrently in order to feel the real benefit of multi-threading, task based or asynchronous programming.

Try see things from a grand picture point of view. Understand the over all modelling of a specific example and see how these methodologies are implemented. It'll easy to see the difference and help understand when and where to use which.