# VS Threads/Tasks are not shown while executing Task.Delay

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, parallel-processing, task

When I execute a program, I noticed that when the code is inside Task.Delay no tasks or threads are showing up in the debugger.

No tasks are showing in the tasks window or parallel stacks window (maybe because the task is created after the delay is complete).

The threads in the threads window exist, but they are in a native unknown piece of code, so no call stack is shown.

An example can be shown in the photo below:

[Threads and Parallel stacks windows status while inside task.delay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mP6Q2.png)

Code example:

```
public static async Task TaskC()
{
    Console.WriteLine("c before");
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    Console.WriteLine("c before");
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var c = TaskC();
    int[] dd = new int[3];
    dd[0] = 0;
    dd[1] = 1;
    dd[2] = 2;
    Parallel.ForEach(dd, async (e) => { await Task.Delay(3000); });
    c.Wait();
}
```

The chance that tasks/threads are in the Task.Delay part of the code is usually the highest because that takes up most of the time.
While in Task.Delay is the most important time to debug and find Tasks and threads, and this is the time where they are invisible to be found...

When we search for bugs we are not always able to log breakpoint hits to find code that reaches Task.Delay, and receiving the current status when the program paused is highly important.

Does anyone know any solution to show the current tasks and threads stack trace when the code is executing Task.Delay?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Threading vs Task-Based vs Asynchronous Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20434220/threading-vs-task-based-vs-asynchronous-programming)

Comment: I am not looking for how threads/tasks work...
I am looking for how to see current tasks/threads in visual studio debugging tools while Task.Delay is executing.

Comment: Feature, not a bug.  That thread actually exists but you can only see it when you enable unmanaged debugging.  It is a dedicated thread inside the CLR that handles all timer objects.  It makes a timer tick when it is due, that activates the task continuation and you'll again see it back.  Not having to pay for code that does nothing is the big picture.

Comment: The problem is that whether I enable unmanaged code or not there still be no stack trace of my program. I will only be able to see nonrelevant code. There is no way to spot all my tasks and threads i activated.

Comment: Some odds that you have not yet discovered the Debug > Windows > Tasks debugger screen.  You'll see Task.Delay(), but you can't get a stack trace for non-running code.