# How vCPU's affect my .net core application performance?

Tags: performance, .net-core, digital-ocean

I'll deploy my net core api project to a cloud hosting, and, I'm confusing about better plan to choose to get a good performance.

All my controller endpoints are async actions, so if I've only one vCPU, what'll happening when many users request at same time? Will they processed one at time?

2 vCPU means 2 parallel processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately without knowing your application, I can't recommend which hosting plan to go with.

However, I can tell you that the number of CPUs will not determine how many requests you can accept at a time.

.NET and .NET Core both support MultiThreading and Task-Based asynchronous patterns, which works on any number of CPUs (even 1 vCPU).  For more information on what these are, check out this stackoverflow question: [Threading vs Task-Based vs Asynchronous Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20434220/threading-vs-task-based-vs-asynchronous-programming)

The number of vCPUs will likely affect your application's performance in CPU bound operations, typically in synchronous algorithms.

If your application is mostly I/O bound, then increasing the number of vCPU may not have any positive impact on performance.

Regardless, you'll likely want to test your application to see how it handles with various configurations.  You can use the Visual Studio profiler to see where hot-spots are in your application to see whether your application is CPU/Memory/IO bound.

Comment: Basicaly, my api application It's Crud operations create, update, delete and list data from mysql database using EF ORM. Is db operations I/O bound or CPU bound?

Comment: Databases, networking, disk, are all I/O operations.